# Viewport performance with new GPU

Tags: 3d-view, performance, hardware

Recently got new GPU (rtx 4080 instead of rtx 2060 super) But viewport performance doesn't improved at all. I want to ask is there some bottle neck or some blender settings to change? My specs (amd ryzen 9 5900x, 32gb 3200ghz ram)